# How to fade background of sliding layer in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am implementing a Sliding layer as shown in this [link](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/sliding-layer/)

I need to fade or gray out the background when I open the sliding layer just like the play store app does in below screen shot
[image]

I tried using:

```
Window window = slidingView.getWindow();

WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
wlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
wlp.dimAmount = (float) 1.0;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

But this doesn't seem to work...nor does

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Why can't you use Google implementation of `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: does DrawerLayout provide that fade effect?

Comment: Sure, it will be the same as in Google Play. Check this link: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: You can even easily change its color and alpha by using `setScrimColor`

Comment: thanks! you can provide the same as an answer and i will be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is to create the same layout as in Google Play consider using `DrawerLayout`.
Here is an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

That layout allows you even easily change fade color and alpha via `setScrimColor` method. The default color is #99000000